# Should i read Webservices (SOAP)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I am thinking about using web services (SOAP) for the web based Timesheet application. There will be around 250-300 people using this website. 
**Development Environment:** VS2010 (VB.NET, ASP.NET with AJAX or telerik) and ORACLE 
**Office Environment:** Web Server is in UK but users will be accessing this application through different countries. ***(Mostly from Europe but few users are in Australia)***

In the past I have used web services for slightly bigger application. My plan is to use web services for data layer.  I will be passing Oracle Store procedures value in XML format and then extract them within the store procedure. Web service function will call the store procedure and then return the dataset object to UI.

(All the database related functions (Data Provider and etc) will be in web services like connection and functions returning datasets.)

There will also be number of reports in this application especially for finance.

In future, I will develop few other (small – medium) size applications using this web services.

[image]

> **I am wondering if the web service will slow down the performance?**

Comment: In my experience adding the service layer when you don't really need one causes other problems such as difficulty getting the just fields you want from a lazy-loaded ORM when you've got large volumes of data.

Comment: I have used web services for three years and never had a problem accessing large data. I learned it from experience developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course using a webservice for data retrieval will slow down the performance of the application, because you add another layer. Data will have to be (de)serialized, which takes processing time.

What is the alternative? If you don't use a webservice, then you'll have to write the data access code in a separate project that your ASP.Net site will reference and use, but it requires a direct connection between the database server and your web server. If that won't be a problem: use the most direct approach. The less code, the less possible bugs.

If you however want the client to get live data through these webservices (e.g. via AJAX), or if you want to create applications that can run everywhere and refer to the data, a webservice definitely is the way to go.

Comment: Could you please explain this in detail: "If you however want the client to get live data through these webservices (e.g. via AJAX), or if you want to create applications that can run everywhere and refer to the data, a webservice definitely is the way to go."

Comment: You can call web services directly from JavaScript running on the clients browser.  Thus your page doesn't have to post back data to the server.  The other benefit of using services over direct access is you could easily write a native application version of you'r website using the same data access layer.

Comment: Hi Rene, i am agreed that i can use the same web services for other applications which i am planning to do. I am just thinking about performance becuase adding one layer would decrease performance as compare to direct connection to DB. On the other hand web service is good in the situation where DB Schema needs to be updated. Security is not really a big concern for Timesheet application.